# Playing movies off our iPad at the cottage

Tags: itunes, ipad, hdmi

Our cottage does not have broadband access (even 3G/LTE is really marginal) so I'm trying to find a solution so we can get some movies at home and then watch them. At the cottage we have an Epson projector and a TV with HDMI.

We purchased a Lightning->HDMI connector, but when we attempt to play movies we downloaded to the iPad from iTunes, it states this is not allowed. I honestly don't recall what happens when we try the VGA input to the projector, but I seem to recall is says the same thing. And I tried getting the non-HD versions and that did the same thing.

So is there any way to do this? I know there have been licensing changes recently, does it effect any of this? Is there a setting I can use or some other type of connector that allows this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best, but not least expensive, option is to buy an [Apple TV](https://www.apple.com/tv/).

This will allow you to [AirPlay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289) movies from your iPad (as well as any other Apple device) to your HDTV without using any cables.

I personally use my Apple TV to do this exact thing on TVs where we don't have a cable connection.

You can buy a new or used one but I wouldn't buy a used one older than version 3.

The movies you're trying to play using the cable might have [HDCP copyright protection](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht202044).

Comment: Will this work without a WiFi router? I know there's some ad-hoc capabilities in many Apple products, but is this one of them?

Comment: And since these movies are from Apple, and obviously do have HDCP, what do I do? How would playing these on an AppleTV help, especially with the projector's VGA connector?

Comment: On [this Apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201343) it references 'peer-to-peer' AirPlay which "lets visitors connect their Mac or iOS device to your Apple TV without passwords or connecting to your Wi-Fi network".  Take a look to make sure you meet the min req.  Regarding the HDCP, you can go from the Apple TV directly to the TV via HDMI, you don't need to use the projector.